# Php How to get UNION result in same column

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I need your help, I have two tables sale and purchase, my requirement is to get result of sale and purchase in same column if the month is same. I am using below code.

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount,
    DATE_FORMAT(saledate,'%M %Y') as saledate,
    null as recovery 
    FROM `advertisercv` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(saledate, '%M %Y')
UNION all
SELECT null,
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') as date,
    SUM(amount) 
    FROM `paymentsrec` 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y')");
?>
```

result:

```
S.No    Month      Sale     Recovery
1   April-2016     10000    
2   April-2016              4000    
2   January-2017    5000    
3   January-2017            3000
```

expected result is:

```
S.No    Month      Sale     Recovery
1   April-2016     10000    4000    
2   January-2017    5000    3000
```

Comment: Can you provide your table schema? Is saledate of type TIMESTAMP or DATETIME? Also seems that your code my be susceptible to SQL Injection you should consider using prepared statements.

Comment: Instead of a union, you should use a JOIN on date and any other column that relates the rows. (customer id?)

Answer (score 0):

By using a *left join*, you can match up the rows in the two tables. I suggest using a left join since there may be rows in the first table that don't have matching rows in the second table. The query below will show all rows in advertisecv with totals for matching rows in paymentsrec. The if function replacing missing row data with zero so that the sum function works correctly.

I also added one more column just as an example of what you can do when you use the join between columns that are in different tables.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(a.`saledate`,'%M %Y') as `saledate`,
    SUM(a.`amount`) as `Sale`,
    SUM(IF(b.`amount` IS NULL,0,b.`amount`)) as `Recovery`
    SUM(a.`amount`) - SUM(IF(b.`amount` IS NULL,0,b.`amount`)) as `Balance Outstanding`
FROM `advertisercv` a
LEFT JOIN `paymentsrec` b
ON DATE_FORMAT(a.`saledate`,'%M %Y) = DATE_FORMAT(b.`saledate`,'%M %Y')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.`saledate`,'%Y %m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(a.`saledate`,'%Y %m')
```